# How to choose Restore Point Directory in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, window, system-restore, nvme

I have a 500 Go NVME (C:/) as windows boot drive and 4To HDD, I want to save the windows restoration point on my HDD but it seems that it can only save it on the C:/ drive itself as below.

[Windows Restoration Point screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCPhE.png)

Is there a way to change the saving directory ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

On every Windows drive, even on external USB drives, you’ll find a hidden
"System Volume Information" folder, where
Restore Points are stored, together with other important data such as
tracking databases for repairing shortcuts and linked documents and
indexing data for fast file searches.

This is a critical operating system folder which cannot be relocated,
because it is on the root of every drive.
Any hacking of its contents can seriously destabilize Windows.
The most you can do is minimize its size.

If it is taking up too much disk space, you may reduce the allocated space:

- Click Start
- Type `system restore` and click "Create a restore point"
- Click on drive `C:`
- Click *Configure*
- Under *Disk Space Usage* you may drag the slider to the amount you like
- Click *Apply* and/or *OK*

Comment: Is the answer then simply that you can't? There is no option in Windows to change the location of where restore points are saved?

Comment: @AuntJemima: I clarified my answer.